# cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and Guzzle's latest version.

I'm trying to make batched pool requests to an external website. This has been working fine until now, but I assume that since the data that I'm fetching became bigger, I started getting these CURL errors after **exactly 2 minutes of waiting time**:

`cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

I use Guzzle's concurrent pool requests:

```
new Pool($client, $requests($urls, $headers), ...)
```

The headers I'm sending only include an `Authorization` header, nothing else is specified.

I was searching on Goolge to find the solution, but couldn't seem to find aynthing realted to this issue exactly.

I've found that it might be `Content-length` but I'm not setting any content length. Or maybe it's that I need to set a `Keep-alive`.

Anyone know what might be the problem here? If you need any more information, please ask for it in the comments below this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I changed,

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null to 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and run command

```
php artisan config:cache
```